# AppDomain.CreateInstance is obsolete

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I found this code that VS said is obsolete:

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(serviceName, null);
using (AssemblyInstaller installer = domain.CreateInstance(typeof(AssemblyInstaller).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AssemblyInstaller).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.ExactBinding, null, new Object[] { $"{filePath}/{serviceName}.exe", new String[] { } }, null, null, null).Unwrap() as AssemblyInstaller)
{   
   installer.Commit(state);
   installer.Uninstall(state);
}
AppDomain.Unload(domain);
```

Basically, in this code I want to unistall a service, and then delete all files.
The problem is that VS says:

'AppDomain.CreateInstance(string, string, bool, BindingFlags, Binder, object[], CultureInfo, object[], Evidence)' está obsoleto: 'Methods which use evidence to sandbox are obsolete and will be removed in a future release of the .NET Framework. Please use an overload of CreateInstance which does not take an Evidence parameter.

I am Trying to change this, but any change make that I cant delete the files, or that the service dont be unistall....

Anyone could help me how do in the correct way?

Thanks!